# Haskell check integer first element to process an ID number

Tags: list, haskell

I'm a newbie in haskell!
I need to write a function that process an ID number. I need to check the first digit of the integer number. If the number is 1 or 3 then the client is male, if the number is 2 or 4 then female. I think I need a helper function which splitting the long integer number to an integer list.
The fuction called szemelyinem, it has one parameter/argument which is a 11 long integer number.

This is the spliting function:

```
split :: Integral x => x -> [x]      
split 0 = []
split x = split (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
```

In my head the notion is Split the long number then load it to the function, then check the first element in the list and return with one string. But I don't know how to start this :/

I have an example like this:

```
szemelyinem 40504291247
Result: "female"
```

Comment: can you write a function, say `foo`, that turns an `Integer` number into a list of its digits?

Comment: in this case here I don't think you need generic `Integral`s - I don't even think you need to split it into a list of `Int`s - could you write your function if you had a list of `Char`s? Do you know any function that will turn your number into a list or `Char`? (hint: `String = [Char]`

Comment: another hint: the pattern you can get the first element from a list either with `head` or (would prefer that) by using pattern-matching against a `firstEl : restEl` pattern

Comment: Honestly, not really. By the way this is a homework but my teacher showed us some basic things. So at this moment I'm sad. In java or C++ this gonna be a 5 minutes task,but in Haskell this is a nightmare so far.

Comment: Are IDs *always* 11 digits long? If so, can you just divide by 10^10 and be done?

Comment: play a bit with `head (show 42)` in ghci (change the number etc.) - notice anything?

Comment: can you take this `isFemale n = let d = head (show n) in d == '2' || d == '4'` and work with it? Maybe add another helper and combine both into what you need?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I figured it out. First I split the integer number to a array, then I reversed the array. For third step I dropped the unnecessary numbers, then transformed the array to int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the first step.

```
split :: Integral x => x -> [x]
split 0 = []
split x = split (x `div` 10) ++ [x `mod` 10]
```

This is the second.

```
rev:: [Integer] -> [Integer]
rev [] = []
rev (h:t) = rev t ++ [h]
```

This is the third step

```
nemdel :: [Integer] -> [Integer]          
nemdel  [] = []
nemdel (h:t) = drop 10 (h:t)
```

This is the fourth.

```
listtonumb:: [Integer] -> Integer
listtonumb = foldl addDigit 0
   where addDigit num d = 10*num + d
```

And the last one.

```
szemelyinem :: Integer -> [Char]
szemelyinem szam =
    if listtonumb(nemdel(rev(split szam)))  == 1 || listtonumb(nemdel(rev(split szam))) == 3
         then "male"
    else if listtonumb(nemdel(rev(split szam))) == 2 || listtonumb(nemdel(rev(split szam))) == 4
         then "Female"
         else error "Bad ID"
```

I'm sure about that is a complex way to do this shit.

Comment: a few comments: `nemdel` can just be `nemdel = drop 10 `, you don't need `rev` if you do ```split x = (x `mod` 10) : split (x `div` 10)``` instead, you might want to introduce a local binding like `let n = listtonumb(nemdel(rev(split szam))) in ...` so you don't have to rewrite the long expression again and again, I'd use `String` instead of `[Char]` (but it's a synonym so it does not really matter)

Comment: also instead of `drop`ing 10 you can let keep your `split` function and use `take 1` instead ;) - of if you already have the `(h:t)` pattern just return `[h]` ;)